# Adding a collection to a running meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-up, minimongo

I am trying to add a new collection to deployed meteor app.
I've deployed my app using meteor up.
I am using only the server-side of the meteor app for my ionic 2 app.
I've tried to use the mongo CLI on the server but I got this error while trying to insert smething to that list `insert failed: Method not found` 
So my question is:
Is there a way for me to add a collection to a mup deployed app ? 
if not, Is there a way to keep my other collections data after running `mup deploy` again with the new collection ? 
Thanks in advance, Shahar.

Comment: The Meteor collection definition should have no effect on data stored in the MongoDB database. Unless your app code deletes data, nothing should be lost. Make the desired changes to your code and re-deploy. What are you concerned might happen?

Comment: Thanks that's what I did and it worked, somehow I thought it will delete and reset my db. Sorry for the silly question.

Answer (score 0):

I made the desired changes to my code and re-deployed the app, nothing was deleted, sorry for the silly question.